# True Dependency Injection

Tags: angularjs

Let's assume that I have the below code.

```
$scope.rateApp = function () {
    Service.rateApp(true);
}
```

When I don't include the Service as a requirement to the controller, AngularJs is going to kick me by saying :

```
ReferenceError: Service is not defined
```

But it's told that AngularJs support dependency injection.

My question is if AngularJs really supports dependency injection, shouldn't it be injecting the requierd service automatically to the code?

Why it makes us to specify the list of dependencies? Does my question makes sense or I am asking a dumb question without RTFM?

Comment: I guess the name of DI can be confusing. Have you tried to get acquainted with [false dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)? You're asking about defining global variables automatically for you, and that would serve quite the opposite purpose. Don't judge a book by its cover.

Answer (score 0):

The Dependency Injection pattern has always required objects to specify the dependencies they require.

> In software engineering, dependency injection is a software design pattern that implements inversion of control for software libraries. Caller delegates to an external framework the control flow of discovering and importing a service or software module.

How those dependencies are provided varies based on the Injection framework, and always requires at least some setup to register the modules that will be requested.

In AngularJS, you typically register your Service with the Module Factory, as shown in the documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: I have read all these docs. and that's where I got this question. Wouldn't it be smart to do the other way around? If not, I believe, this should not be named as Dependency Injection.

Comment: It is named so because you inject external dependencies by intent into a piece of code, not because they are injected by framework. It will start to make more sense when you will get to unit testing and making reusable components.

Comment: The name "Dependency Injection" primarily refers to the action that is done to your objects, and not about the means by which the injection is performed. It is all about individual objects yielding control of their dependencies instead of managing them internally.